# How do I get Blacksmith Plans in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just learned from looking at the official Diablo 3 site that there are a variety of [Blacksmith Plans](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/) that you have to require in order to craft certain rare and legendary items.  I have not seen any of these drop so far in my game, nor have I seen them for purchase at the Blacksmith or other vendors.

Does anyone know how you get access to these plans?

Comment: When you say that you haven't seen any drop yet, what Act/difficulty are you in?

Comment: Act 3 on Normal.  I'm aware that they might drop later, but I was curious when I could expect to see them with some regularity.  I ask because there are items from Plans usable at level 20, which made me believe that I should have already found Plans.

Comment: Well, I know for sure that the Plans for Staff of Herding drop from Izual in Act 4. Extrapolating from that, they are just another drop. Take a look at the auction house and see if anyone has any spare. Also, they are shared across the characters on your account, which might explain the seeming level requirements not matching up to you finding them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/), there are 3 Normal, 87 Rare, and 39 Legendary Blacksmith Plans. We know that the three normal ones are dropped by Izual in Act 4 on the respective difficulty levels.

Anecdotally by forum posts, it looks like people are finding one or two per difficulty ([bnet forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149006299)) from random monster/champion/boss drops, although one person notes none found on his way to Inferno. So far the only non-Blizzard list this gamer found was at [d3db](http://d3db.com/item?c=_blacksmith-plan), and it just lists "Drop" as the source of each of the plans.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't seen a single plan drop and I'm on Act IV Hell.

Comment: I finally had one drop in Act 1 Inferno from an elite while going to the Warden.

Comment: I've taken 2 classes all the way through to Act 1 Inferno and have yet to see a plan drop.

Answer (score 1):

Any rare mobs can drop the pattern. I have a friend whose highest character is a Wizard in Act 3 Hell and he has already managed to obtain 3 legendary item patterns, compared to me who has 1 in Inferno Act 3 and Inferno Act 1 and haven't seen 1 drop as yet. The plans are just random but as others have mentioned I have found several rare item patterns in Inferno but typically the basic armour upgrades - nothing outstanding. The only way to obtain the plans is by persisting with the game and killing as many rare/elites are you can. Most people say they get them in Inferno because they farm Inferno for those 1k+ dps weapons or elite items. I don't recall any high level player going back to Normal/NM/Hell to farm when they can quite sufficiently farm Inferno.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the merchant 'Squirt' in act II can sell blacksmith plans in the miscellaneous section. I dont know if you have to be at the end of act II or if you can periodically check throughout the Act, but I saw 5 rare plans, they cost 1.5 mil gold each, and that was on Normal Diff

Answer (score 0):

I bought Diablo 3 for XBox, and so far I got most my drops for blacksmith on nightmare and inferno difficulty level, desert level, as well as final act at the spire and act 3 where you have to kill ballistas. Down the last bridge.